# Dynamically Change isAccessibilityElement

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I've got a bit of a weird situation. I need to have an element not be read out by VoiceOver when I use the 2 finger swipe method, but to be read when tapping on it still.

The object is part of a TableView cell, and I've given the TableView cell its own accessibilityLabel, because it contains two interactive elements, one of which doesn't actually need to be read when tapped on, so I've disabled its accessibility property.

However, my other one needs to be read still when tapped on. The issue is, it's already being read as part of the cell's accessibilityLabel, and then it is read again because it is still an accessible element. Is there any way to differentiate between why VoiceOver is reading an element? Or to dynamically change the accessibilityLabel?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically change `accessibilityLabel` simply by assigning it or overriding the method on the accessible view. However, you shouldn't rely on VoiceOver respecting the change in real time.

Users can navigate via tap or swipe and expect elements to persist regardless of how they were reached. In general, I discourage clever solutions that assume how users interact with VoiceOver.

I'd encourage you to either override the cell summary to omit the label or disable accessibility on the label and leave the content in the cell summary.